# Setting color options on Highchart bar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working on [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/0ew8gtoe/). Why is the plot options color not getting the bar colors from the Color options (two colors)? As you can see it is taking color from only one for both colors.

```
$(function () {
    chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
          type: 'bar'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                colorByPoint: true
            },
              series: {
                pointWidth: 50
            }
        },
        colors: [
            '#D9844B',
            '#3F4539'],
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Test',
            style: {
                color: '#2d2d2d',
                fontWeight: 'normal',
                fontSize: '11',
                marginBottom: '30'
            }
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Ecology & Economics', 'Economics Only'],

        },
        yAxis: {
            tickInterval: 50,
            max: 300,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of ROR Facilities'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.x + '  <b> : ' + this.y + '</b>';
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,

                color: '#2d2d2d',
                align: 'right',
                x: -40,
                y: 0,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the documentation is wrong.  It says that `colorByPoint` is a bar/column option but you are correct it isn't working.  Moving it to a series option and it does work:

```
    plotOptions: {            
          series: {
            pointWidth: 50,
            colorByPoint: true
        }
    },
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ew8gtoe/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Referring to @Mark answer, the Highcharts documentation is correct.

There is a difference between defining options in every series in Highcharts, especially **bar** and **column** series are different series.

You are using **bar** series (chart.type: 'bar'), but in plotOptions you are defining colorByPoint only for a **column** series which, obviously, does not even exist in your chart.

You have many solutions:

**1) You can define colorByPoint inside a specific series options:**

```
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },

  series: [{
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [4, 3, 5]
  }]
```

**2) you can define colorByPoint for all series:**

```
chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
        colorByPoint: true
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [4, 3, 5]
  }]
```

**3) You can define colorByPoint for all bar type series:**

```
chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },

  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
        colorByPoint: true
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [4, 3, 5]
  }]
```

**4) You can use inverted column type series (which is actually a bar series):**

```
chart: {
    type: 'column',
    inverted: true
  },

  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      colorByPoint: true
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [4, 3, 5]
  }]
```

**5) You can also define the color for each bar separately:**

```
series: [{
    type: 'bar',
    data: [{
      y: 4,
      color: 'red'
    }, {
      y: 3,
      color: 'blue'
    }, {
      y: 5,
      color: 'green'
    }]
  }]
```

And even more. Above solution should be enough for you.
Remember, plotOptions.column will not work for chart.type: 'bar'.